# runtime permission for getclassloader() failed in iced tea web

Tags: classloader, java-web-start, icedtea-web

I made and entry in java.policy file in linux machine as below to resolve the issue of getClassLoader() in my code while using IcedTeaWeb. but still the below statement "cls.getClassLoader()" is causing issue.
**permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "getClassLoader";**

Please update how to resolve this issue

Comment: Can you please add the version of IcedTeaWeb and Java (+vendor) that you are using.

Comment: IcedTeaWeb version - rhel2        
jdk verison - java 18.0 openJDK

Comment: I assume it should be 1.8.0 ?

Comment: You are using the word “below” two times and in each case, it looks like you have forgotten to actually include the particular information “below” the referring sentence.